# Use NGINX Rate Limiting with tokens

Tags: api, nginx, rate-limiting

I need to limit access to our API to 10 requests / second.

This is the zone I'm using based on their documentation:

> limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:10m rate=10r/s;

This zone uses the user IP address as identification to rate the usage limit. Often, people uses the same IP address to access our systems.

I'm wondering if it's possible to use the user tokenId as identification for the rate limit. All of our requests contains a `tokenID` parameter in the URL: `www.example.com/api/events/?tokenID=*****`.

Any clues?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I tried creating the zone:
`limit_req_zone "$tokenid" zone=limit:10m rate=1r/s;` (1 r/s for testing)
and extracting the `$tokenid` variable like this:

```
limit_req_zone "$tokenid" zone=limit:10m rate=1r/s;

server {
   ...

   location ~ \.php {
      ...
      if ($args ~* "tokenID=([^&]+)") {
          set $tokenid "$1";
      }
      ...
   }
}
```

The variable `$tokenid` does contain the exact token (tested adding a header to the response), but it does not seem to update its value used by `limit_req_zone`.

Comment: Try using `$arg_tokenID` instead of `$token`

Comment: @TarunLalwani I tried with several arguments, it works perfectly, but with `tokenID` it doesn't. Could it be because it is case sensitive?

Comment: do you mean the `tokenID` could be `tokenid` also? or the actual value of token is case in-sensitive in the app?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I tried with both `tokenID` and `tokenid` and neither seems to work, but using another argument, like `action` or anything else, it works. PS: `tokenID` has around 64 characters, could this affect it?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I tested it here. The size affects indeed. I tried with a 4 character `tokenID` and it works fine, but with 64 characters it doesn't work.

Comment: Ask on the nginx forums then and see if you can get more details

Comment: @TarunLalwani The limit is 64kb for each key, so it's ok (https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/modules/ngx_http_limit_req_module.c). I found the problem. On `siege`, it's not url encoding the variable, and in the browser it is. So, in the browser, the token starts with `%242a%2408%24` and in siege, it starts with `$2a$08$`. 

I don't think that's a problem, because in a real world case, the token sent by the user in a device will have the same format always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The suggestion made by @TarunLalwani actually works.

I should use `$arg_tokenID` instead of extracting it from the URI and setting into a variable.

The final config file looks like this:

```
limit_req_zone "$arg_tokenID" zone=limit:10m rate=10r/s;

server {
   ...
   limit_req zone=limit burst=10;
   ...
}
```

Comment: can you please post the complete config which got you the $arg_tokenID working?

Comment: I would like to see this as well if you can post example of complete configuration.